# DJI Bridge produces ipv6 address and won't connect

Tags: ios, dji-sdk

While writing an iOS Application with the DJI SDK, I am trying to connect the SDK to the drone via the `bridged` mode.  This mode takes in an ipv4 address, however when I boot up the DJI Bridge app on either my iPhone or my iPad, the displayed address is ipv6.  Supplying the ipv6 value in the code does not produce a connected drone.

```
sdkManager.enableBridgeMode(withBridgeAppIP: "ipv6 address")
```

The issue also exists against the DJI Bridge github project: https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-iOS/issues/281

Comment: good luck. i played with all other dji sdk, osdk psdk wsdk. just not msdk-ios. You can try to find bruce in dev@dji.com   or   join the DJI wechat developer group which there are many active discussions.

Comment: I've experienced this issue before when connecting to a new WiFi network but rebooting the iPad/iPhone running the bridge app fixed it for me

Answer (score 1):

Turning off ipv6 support on my router forced all my connected devices back to ipv4, and now DJI Bridge works fine.